# philogb/Treemap only renders undefined

Tags: javascript, graph, treemap, infovis

I am trying to use https://github.com/philogb/jit to create a treemap of data coming from `top`. The data looks like:

```
"{"rsyslogd":{"children":[{"children":[],"data":{"PID":"17670","$color":"#D40106","cmdinfo":"<br><b>USER</b>:syslog<br><b>PR</b>:20<br><b>NI</b>:0<br><b>VIRT</b>:383m<br><b>RES</b>:5412<br><b>SHR</b>:1108<br><b>S</b>:S<br><b>CPU</b>:177%<br>%<b>MEM</b>:0.3%<br><b>TIME+</b>:32230:25<br>","$area":4},"id":"proc-1-17670","name":"rsyslogd"}],"data":{"PID":"rsyslogd","$area":50},"id":"proc-rsyslogd","name":"rsyslogd(1)"},"init":{"children":[{"children":[],"data":{"PID":"1","$color":"#0EAB06","cmdinfo":"<br><b>USER</b>:root<br><b>PR</b>:20<br><b>NI</b>:0<br><b>VIRT</b>:23584<br><b>RES</b>:1324<br><b>SHR</b>:1044<br><b>S</b>:S<br><b>CPU</b>:0%<br>%<b>MEM</b>:0.1%<br><b>TIME+</b>:0:00.10<br>","$area":2},"id":"proc-1-1","name":"init"}],"data":{"PID":"init","$area":30},"id":"proc-init","name":"init(1)"},"dbus-daemon":{"children":[{"children":[],"data":{"PID":"88","$color":"#0EAB06","cmdinfo":"<br><b>USER</b>:messageb<br><b>PR</b>:20<br><b>NI</b>:0<br><b>VIRT</b>:23556<br><b>RES</b>:328<br><b>SHR</b>:324<br><b>S</b>:S<br><b>CPU</b>:0%<br>%<b>MEM</b>:0.0%<br><b>TIME+</b>:0:00.00<br>","$area":1},"id":"proc-1-88","name":"dbus-daemon"}],"data":{"PID":"dbus-daemon","$area":20},"id":"proc-dbus-daemon","name":"dbus-daemon(1)"},"sshd":{"children":[{"children":[],"data":{"PID":"183","$color":"#0EAB06","cmdinfo":"<br><b>USER</b>:root<br><b>PR</b>:20<br><b>NI</b>:0<br><b>VIRT</b>:49436<br><b>RES</b>:1640<br><b>SHR</b>:1528<br><b>S</b>:S<br><b>CPU</b>:0%<br>%<b>MEM</b>:0.1%<br><b>TIME+</b>:0:00.14<br>","$area":2},"id":"proc-1-183","name":"sshd"}],"data":{"PID":"sshd","$area":30},"id":"proc-sshd","name":"sshd(1)"},"cron":{"children":[{"children":[],"data":{"PID":"209","$color":"#0EAB06","cmdinfo":"<br><b>USER</b>:root<br><b>PR</b>:20<br><b>NI</b>:0<br><b>VIRT</b>:18900<br><b>RES</b>:704<br><b>SHR</b>:628<br><b>S</b>:S<br><b>CPU</b>:0%<br>%<b>MEM</b>:0.0%<br><b>TIME+</b>:0:01.34<br>","$area":1},"id":"proc-1-209","name":"cron"}],"data":{"PID":"cron","$area":20},"id":"proc-cron","name":"cron(1)"},"mysqld":{"children":[{"children":[],"data":{"PID":"240","$color":"#0EAB06","cmdinfo":"<br><b>USER</b>:mysql<br><b>PR</b>:20<br><b>NI</b>:0<br><b>VIRT</b>:334m<br><b>RES</b>:49m<br><b>SHR</b>:3988<br><b>S</b>:S<br><b>CPU</b>:0%<br>%<b>MEM</b>:3.2%<br><b>TIME+</b>:58:21.44<br>","$area":33},"id":"proc-1-240","name":"mysqld"}],"data":{"PID":"mysqld","$area":340},"id":"proc-mysqld","name":"mysqld(1)"},"sendmail-mta":{"children":[{"children":[],"data":{"PID":"317","$color":"#0EAB06","cmdinfo":"<br><b>USER</b>:root<br><b>PR</b>:20<br><b>NI</b>:0<br><b>VIRT</b>:68284<br><b>RES</b>:844<br><b>SHR</b>:648<br><b>S</b>:S<br><b>CPU</b>:0%<br>%<b>MEM</b>:0.1%<br><b>TIME+</b>:0:31.61<br>","$area":2},"id":"proc-1-317","name":"sendmail-mta"}],"data":{"PID":"sendmail-mta","$area":30},"id":"proc-sendmail-mta","name":"sendmail-mta(1)"},"apache2":{"children":[{"children":[],"data":{"PID":"372","$color":"#0EAB06","cmdinfo":"<br><b>USER</b>:root<br><b>PR</b>:20<br><b>NI</b>:0<br><b>VIRT</b>:342m<br><b>RES</b>:8404<br><b>SHR</b>:5412<br><b>S</b>:S<br><b>CPU</b>:0%<br>%<b>MEM</b>:0.5%<br><b>TIME+</b>:0:50.46<br>","$area":6},"id":"proc-1-372","name":"apache2"},{"children":[],"data":{"PID":"24804","$color":"#0EAB06","cmdinfo":"<br><b>USER</b>:www-data<br><b>PR</b>:20<br><b>NI</b>:0<br><b>VIRT</b>:369m<br><b>RES</b>:81m<br><b>SHR</b>:56m<br><b>S</b>:S<br><b>CPU</b>:0%<br>%<b>MEM</b>:5.3%<br><b>TIME+</b>:0:07.93<br>","$area":54},"id":"proc-1-24804","name":"apache2"},{"children":[],"data":{"PID":"24821","$color":"#0EAB06","cmdinfo":"<br><b>USER</b>:www-data<br><b>PR</b>:20<br><b>NI</b>:0<br><b>VIRT</b>:366m<br><b>RES</b>:66m<br><b>SHR</b>:41m<br><b>S</b>:S<br><b>CPU</b>:0%<br>%<b>MEM</b>:4.3%<br><b>TIME+</b>:0:06.27<br>","$area":44},"id":"proc-1-24821","name":"apache2"},{"children":[],"data":{"PID":"24828","$color":"#0EAB06","cmdinfo":"<br><b>USER</b>:www-data<br><b>PR</b>:20<br><b>NI</b>:0<br><b>VIRT</b>:359m<br><b>RES</b>:71m<br><b>SHR</b>:53m<br><b>S</b>:S<br><b>CPU</b>:0%<br>%<b>MEM</b>:4.7%<br><b>TIME+</b>:0:06.39<br>","$area":48},"id":"proc-1-24828","name":"apache2"},{"children":[],"data":{"PID":"24832","$color":"#0EAB06","cmdinfo":"<br><b>USER</b>:www-data<br><b>PR</b>:20<br><b>NI</b>:0<br><b>VIRT</b>:361m<br><b>RES</b>:70m<br><b>SHR</b>:52m<br><b>S</b>:S<br><b>CPU</b>:0%<br>%<b>MEM</b>:4.6%<br><b>TIME+</b>:0:04.18<br>","$area":47},"id":"proc-1-24832","name":"apache2"},{"children":[],"data":{"PID":"24860","$color":"#0EAB06","cmdinfo":"<br><b>USER</b>:www-data<br><b>PR</b>:20<br><b>NI</b>:0<br><b>VIRT</b>:368m<br><b>RES</b>:77m<br><b>SHR</b>:53m<br><b>S</b>:S<br><b>CPU</b>:0%<br>%<b>MEM</b>:5.1%<br><b>TIME+</b>:0:06.15<br>","$area":52},"id":"proc-1-24860","name":"apache2"},{"children":[],"data":{"PID":"24862","$color":"#0EAB06","cmdinfo":"<br><b>USER</b>:www-data<br><b>PR</b>:20<br><b>NI</b>:0<br><b>VIRT</b>:361m<br><b>RES</b>:58m<br><b>SHR</b>:41m<br><b>S</b>:S<br><b>CPU</b>:0%<br>%<b>MEM</b>:3.8%<br><b>TIME+</b>:0:03.86<br>","$area":39},"id":"proc-1-24862","name":"apache2"},{"children":[],"data":{"PID":"24878","$color":"#0EAB06","cmdinfo":"<br><b>USER</b>:www-data<br><b>PR</b>:20<br><b>NI</b>:0<br><b>VIRT</b>:359m<br><b>RES</b>:51m<br><b>SHR</b>:34m<br><b>S</b>:S<br><b>CPU</b>:0%<br>%<b>MEM</b>:3.4%<br><b>TIME+</b>:0:01.54<br>","$area":35},"id":"proc-1-24878","name":"apache2"},{"children":[],"data":{"PID":"24882","$color":"#0EAB06","cmdinfo":"<br><b>USER</b>:www-data<br><b>PR</b>:20<br><b>NI</b>:0<br><b>VIRT</b>:362m<br><b>RES</b>:53m<br><b>SHR</b>:34m<br><b>S</b>:S<br><b>CPU</b>:0%<br>%<b>MEM</b>:3.5%<br><b>TIME+</b>:0:01.60<br>","$area":36},"id":"proc-1-24882","name":"apache2"},{"children":[],"data":{"PID":"24885","$color":"#0EAB06","cmdinfo":"<br><b>USER</b>:www-data<br><b>PR</b>:20<br><b>NI</b>:0<br><b>VIRT</b>:366m<br><b>RES</b>:61m<br><b>SHR</b>:38m<br><b>S</b>:S<br><b>CPU</b>:0%<br>%<b>MEM</b>:4.0%<br><b>TIME+</b>:0:02.65<br>","$area":41},"id":"proc-1-24885","name":"apache2"},{"children":[],"data":{"PID":"24887","$color":"#0EAB06","cmdinfo":"<br><b>USER</b>:www-data<br><b>PR</b>:20<br><b>NI</b>:0<br><b>VIRT</b>:366m<br><b>RES</b>:73m<br><b>SHR</b>:50m<br><b>S</b>:S<br><b>CPU</b>:0%<br>%<b>MEM</b>:4.8%<br><b>TIME+</b>:0:02.04<br>","$area":49},"id":"proc-1-24887","name":"apache2"},{"children":[],"data":{"PID":"24888","$color":"#0EAB06","cmdinfo":"<br><b>USER</b>:www-data<br><b>PR</b>:20<br><b>NI</b>:0<br><b>VIRT</b>:363m<br><b>RES</b>:60m<br><b>SHR</b>:36m<br><b>S</b>:S<br><b>CPU</b>:0%<br>%<b>MEM</b>:3.9%<br><b>TIME+</b>:0:02.34<br>","$area":40},"id":"proc-1-24888","name":"apache2"},{"children":[],"data":{"PID":"24889","$color":"#0EAB06","cmdinfo":"<br><b>USER</b>:www-data<br><b>PR</b>:20<br><b>NI</b>:0<br><b>VIRT</b>:363m<br><b>RES</b>:61m<br><b>SHR</b>:39m<br><b>S</b>:S<br><b>CPU</b>:0%<br>%<b>MEM</b>:4.0%<br><b>TIME+</b>:0:02.81<br>","$area":41},"id":"proc-1-24889","name":"apache2"},{"children":[],"data":{"PID":"24892","$color":"#0EAB06","cmdinfo":"<br><b>USER</b>:www-data<br><b>PR</b>:20<br><b>NI</b>:0<br><b>VIRT</b>:356m<br><b>RES</b>:47m<br><b>SHR</b>:33m<br><b>S</b>:S<br><b>CPU</b>:0%<br>%<b>MEM</b>:3.1%<br><b>TIME+</b>:0:02.60<br>","$area":32},"id":"proc-1-24892","name":"apache2"},{"children":[],"data":{"PID":"24893","$color":"#0EAB06","cmdinfo":"<br><b>USER</b>:www-data<br><b>PR</b>:20<br><b>NI</b>:0<br><b>VIRT</b>:355m<br><b>RES</b>:49m<br><b>SHR</b>:33m<br><b>S</b>:S<br><b>CPU</b>:0%<br>%<b>MEM</b>:3.2%<br><b>TIME+</b>:0:01.70<br>","$area":33},"id":"proc-1-24893","name":"apache2"},{"children":[],"data":{"PID":"24897","$color":"#0EAB06","cmdinfo":"<br><b>USER</b>:www-data<br><b>PR</b>:20<br><b>NI</b>:0<br><b>VIRT</b>:363m<br><b>RES</b>:62m<br><b>SHR</b>:38m<br><b>S</b>:S<br><b>CPU</b>:0%<br>%<b>MEM</b>:4.1%<br><b>TIME+</b>:0:02.44<br>","$area":42},"id":"proc-1-24897","name":"apache2"},{"children":[],"data":{"PID":"24900","$color":"#0EAB06","cmdinfo":"<br><b>USER</b>:www-data<br><b>PR</b>:20<br><b>NI</b>:0<br><b>VIRT</b>:365m<br><b>RES</b>:63m<br><b>SHR</b>:39m<br><b>S</b>:S<br><b>CPU</b>:0%<br>%<b>MEM</b>:4.1%<br><b>TIME+</b>:0:01.82<br>","$area":42},"id":"proc-1-24900","name":"apache2"},{"children":[],"data":{"PID":"24903","$color":"#0EAB06","cmdinfo":"<br><b>USER</b>:www-data<br><b>PR</b>:20<br><b>NI</b>:0<br><b>VIRT</b>:364m<br><b>RES</b>:56m<br><b>SHR</b>:36m<br><b>S</b>:S<br><b>CPU</b>:0%<br>%<b>MEM</b>:3.7%<br><b>TIME+</b>:0:03.43<br>","$area":38},"id":"proc-1-24903","name":"apache2"},{"children":[],"data":{"PID":"24924","$color":"#0EAB06","cmdinfo":"<br><b>USER</b>:www-data<br><b>PR</b>:20<br><b>NI</b>:0<br><b>VIRT</b>:365m<br><b>RES</b>:61m<br><b>SHR</b>:37m<br><b>S</b>:S<br><b>CPU</b>:0%<br>%<b>MEM</b>:4.0%<br><b>TIME+</b>:0:02.13<br>","$area":41},"id":"proc-1-24924","name":"apache2"},{"children":[],"data":{"PID":"24926","$color":"#0EAB06","cmdinfo":"<br><b>USER</b>:www-data<br><b>PR</b>:20<br><b>NI</b>:0<br><b>VIRT</b>:362m<br><b>RES</b>:51m<br><b>SHR</b>:33m<br><b>S</b>:S<br><b>CPU</b>:0%<br>%<b>MEM</b>:3.3%<br><b>TIME+</b>:0:00.81<br>","$area":34},"id":"proc-1-24926","name":"apache2"},{"children":[],"data":{"PID":"24930","$color":"#0EAB06","cmdinfo":"<br><b>USER</b>:www-data<br><b>PR</b>:20<br><b>NI</b>:0<br><b>VIRT</b>:367m<br><b>RES</b>:61m<br><b>SHR</b>:36m<br><b>S</b>:S<br><b>CPU</b>:0%<br>%<b>MEM</b>:4.0%<br><b>TIME+</b>:0:01.32<br>","$area":41},"id":"proc-1-24930","name":"apache2"},{"children":[],"data":{"PID":"24933","$color":"#0EAB06","cmdinfo":"<br><b>USER</b>:www-data<br><b>PR</b>:20<br><b>NI</b>:0<br><b>VIRT</b>:355m<br><b>RES</b>:44m<br><b>SHR</b>:30m<br><b>S</b>:S<br><b>CPU</b>:0%<br>%<b>MEM</b>:2.9%<br><b>TIME+</b>:0:00.56<br>","$area":30},"id":"proc-1-24933","name":"apache2"},{"children":[],"data":{"PID":"24935","$color":"#0EAB06","cmdinfo":"<br><b>USER</b>:www-data<br><b>PR</b>:20<br><b>NI</b>:0<br><b>VIRT</b>:353m<br><b>RES</b>:39m<br><b>SHR</b>:24m<br><b>S</b>:S<br><b>CPU</b>:0%<br>%<b>MEM</b>:2.5%<br><b>TIME+</b>:0:00.28<br>","$area":26},"id":"proc-1-24935","name":"apache2"},{"children":[],"data":{"PID":"24936","$color":"#0EAB06","cmdinfo":"<br><b>USER</b>:www-data<br><b>PR</b>:20<br><b>NI</b>:0<br><b>VIRT</b>:359m<br><b>RES</b>:52m<br><b>SHR</b>:33m<br><b>S</b>:S<br><b>CPU</b>:0%<br>%<b>MEM</b>:3.4%<br><b>TIME+</b>:0:00.98<br>","$area":35},"id":"proc-1-24936","name":"apache2"},{"children":[],"data":{"PID":"24939","$color":"#0EAB06","cmdinfo":"<br><b>USER</b>:www-data<br><b>PR</b>:20<br><b>NI</b>:0<br><b>VIRT</b>:354m<br><b>RES</b>:41m<br><b>SHR</b>:27m<br><b>S</b>:S<br><b>CPU</b>:0%<br>%<b>MEM</b>:2.7%<br><b>TIME+</b>:0:00.28<br>","$area":28},"id":"proc-1-24939","name":"apache2"},{"children":[],"data":{"PID":"24941","$color":"#0EAB06","cmdinfo":"<br><b>USER</b>:www-data<br><b>PR</b>:20<br><b>NI</b>:0<br><b>VIRT</b>:362m<br><b>RES</b>:57m<br><b>SHR</b>:34m<br><b>S</b>:S<br><b>CPU</b>:0%<br>%<b>MEM</b>:3.7%<br><b>TIME+</b>:0:00.43<br>","$area":38},"id":"proc-1-24941","name":"apache2"},{"children":[],"data":{"PID":"24942","$color":"#0EAB06","cmdinfo":"<br><b>USER</b>:www-data<br><b>PR</b>:20<br><b>NI</b>:0<br><b>VIRT</b>:357m<br><b>RES</b>:41m<br><b>SHR</b>:26m<br><b>S</b>:S<br><b>CPU</b>:0%<br>%<b>MEM</b>:2.7%<br><b>TIME+</b>:0:00.31<br>","$area":28},"id":"proc-1-24942","name":"apache2"},{"children":[],"data":{"PID":"24943","$color":"#0EAB06","cmdinfo":"<br><b>USER</b>:www-data<br><b>PR</b>:20<br><b>NI</b>:0<br><b>VIRT</b>:346m<br><b>RES</b>:16m<br><b>SHR</b>:8604<br><b>S</b>:S<br><b>CPU</b>:0%<br>%<b>MEM</b>:1.1%<br><b>TIME+</b>:0:00.09<br>","$area":12},"id":"proc-1-24943","name":"apache2"},{"children":[],"data":{"PID":"24944","$color":"#0EAB06","cmdinfo":"<br><b>USER</b>:www-data<br><b>PR</b>:20<br><b>NI</b>:0<br><b>VIRT</b>:351m<br><b>RES</b>:34m<br><b>SHR</b>:21m<br><b>S</b>:S<br><b>CPU</b>:0%<br>%<b>MEM</b>:2.3%<br><b>TIME+</b>:0:00.18<br>","$area":24},"id":"proc-1-24944","name":"apache2"},{"children":[],"data":{"PID":"24945","$color":"#0EAB06","cmdinfo":"<br><b>USER</b>:www-data<br><b>PR</b>:20<br><b>NI</b>:0<br><b>VIRT</b>:363m<br><b>RES</b>:67m<br><b>SHR</b>:43m<br><b>S</b>:S<br><b>CPU</b>:0%<br>%<b>MEM</b>:4.4%<br><b>TIME+</b>:0:00.99<br>","$area":45},"id":"proc-1-24945","name":"apache2"},{"children":[],"data":{"PID":"24946","$color":"#0EAB06","cmdinfo":"<br><b>USER</b>:www-data<br><b>PR</b>:20<br><b>NI</b>:0<br><b>VIRT</b>:342m<br><b>RES</b>:5552<br><b>SHR</b>:1800<br><b>S</b>:S<br><b>CPU</b>:0%<br>%<b>MEM</b>:0.4%<br><b>TIME+</b>:0:00.03<br>","$area":5},"id":"proc-1-24946","name":"apache2"},{"children":[],"data":{"PID":"24950","$color":"#0EAB06","cmdinfo":"<br><b>USER</b>:www-data<br><b>PR</b>:20<br><b>NI</b>:0<br><b>VIRT</b>:360m<br><b>RES</b>:48m<br><b>SHR</b>:30m<br><b>S</b>:S<br><b>CPU</b>:0%<br>%<b>MEM</b>:3.2%<br><b>TIME+</b>:0:00.39<br>","$area":33},"id":"proc-1-24950","name":"apache2"}],"data":{"PID":"apache2","$area":11400},"id":"proc-apache2","name":"apache2(32)"},"newrelic-daemon":{"children":[{"children":[],"data":{"PID":"399","$color":"#0EAB06","cmdinfo":"<br><b>USER</b>:root<br><b>PR</b>:20<br><b>NI</b>:0<br><b>VIRT</b>:16232<br><b>RES</b>:292<br><b>SHR</b>:288<br><b>S</b>:S<br><b>CPU</b>:0%<br>%<b>MEM</b>:0.0%<br><b>TIME+</b>:0:00.00<br>","$area":1},"id":"proc-1-399","name":"newrelic-daemon"},{"children":[],"data":{"PID":"400","$color":"#0EAB06","cmdinfo":"<br><b>USER</b>:root<br><b>PR</b>:20<br><b>NI</b>:0<br><b>VIRT</b>:264m<br><b>RES</b>:7284<br><b>SHR</b>:2360<br><b>S</b>:S<br><b>CPU</b>:0%<br>%<b>MEM</b>:0.5%<br><b>TIME+</b>:40:33.01<br>","$area":6},"id":"proc-1-400","name":"newrelic-daemon"}],"data":{"PID":"newrelic-daemon","$area":80},"id":"proc-newrelic-daemon","name":"newrelic-daemon(2)"},"top":{"children":[{"children":[],"data":{"PID":"24988","$color":"#0EAB06","cmdinfo":"<br><b>USER</b>:root<br><b>PR</b>:20<br><b>NI</b>:0<br><b>VIRT</b>:19196<br><b>RES</b>:1328<br><b>SHR</b>:1048<br><b>S</b>:R<br><b>CPU</b>:0%<br>%<b>MEM</b>:0.1%<br><b>TIME+</b>:0:00.00<br>","$area":2},"id":"proc-1-24988","name":"top"}],"data":{"PID":"top","$area":30},"id":"proc-top","name":"top(1)"}}"
```

I then convert this into a JavaScript Object using `JSON.parse(...)` and assign it to `data` .

Then the actual InfoVis code:

```
function getCanvasConfig() {
        var ua = navigator.userAgent,
            iStuff = ua.match(/iPhone/i) || ua.match(/iPad/i),
            typeOfCanvas = typeof HTMLCanvasElement,
            nativeCanvasSupport = (typeOfCanvas == 'object' || typeOfCanvas == 'function'),
            textSupport = nativeCanvasSupport
                && (typeof document.createElement('canvas').getContext('2d').fillText == 'function');

        //I'm setting this based on the fact that ExCanvas provides text support for IE
        //and that as of today iPhone/iPad current text support is lame
        return {
            labelType: (!nativeCanvasSupport || (textSupport && !iStuff))? 'Native' : 'HTML',
            nativeTextSupport: (!nativeCanvasSupport || (textSupport && !iStuff)),
            useGradients: nativeCanvasSupport,
            animate: !(iStuff || !nativeCanvasSupport)
        };
    }

    var config = getCanvasConfig();
    var attrs = {id: "infovis"};

    var tmConfig = {
            //where to inject the visualization
            injectInto: attrs.id,
            //parent box title heights
            titleHeight: 15,
            //enable animations
            animate: config.animate,
            //box offsets
            offset: 1,
            //Attach left and right click events
            Events: {
                enable: true,
                onClick: function(node) {
                    if(node) tm.enter(node);
                },
                onRightClick: function() {
                    tm.out();
                }
            },
            duration: 1000,
            //Enable tips
            Tips: {
                enable: true,
                //add positioning offsets
                offsetX: 20,
                offsetY: 20,
                //implement the onShow method to
                //add content to the tooltip when a node
                //is hovered
                onShow: function(tip, node, isLeaf, domElement) {
                    var html = "<div class=\"tip-title\">" + node.name
                        + "</div><div class=\"tip-text\">";
                    var data = node.data;
                    if(data.PID) {
                        html += "<br><b>PID</b>: " + data.PID;
                    }
                    if(data.cmdinfo) {
                        html += ""+ data.cmdinfo +"";
                    }
                    tip.innerHTML =  html;
                }
            },
            //Add the name of the node in the correponding label
            //This method is called once, on label creation.
            onCreateLabel: function(domElement, node){
                domElement.innerHTML = node.name;
                var data = node.data;
                var PID = data.PID;
                var style = domElement.style;
                style.display = '';
                style.border = '1px solid transparent';
                domElement.onclick = function() {
                    $('input#PIDtext').val(PID);
                };
                domElement.onmouseover = function() {
                    style.border = '1px solid #efefef';
                };
                domElement.onmouseout = function() {
                    style.border = '1px solid transparent';
                };
            }
        };

        var tm = new $jit.TM.Squarified(tmConfig);

  tm.loadJSON(data);
  tm.refresh();
```

However, all I keep getting is "undefined" injected into the canvas. Any clues?

Answer (score 0):

Just leaving this here:

The problem was with the data. I need to have a root node with appropriate name & ID that had the rest of the data as children.